# Rank 2 caused collective abort of all racks

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi

The code below tries to finds the max number of an array using [mpi](http://condor.cc.ku.edu/~grobe/docs/intro-MPI-C.shtml). However I keep getting the following error:

> Rank 2 in job 47 caused collective abort of all ranks. 
>   Exit status of rank 2 : killed by signal 9

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc , char * argv[])
{
    int myRank , numOfProcesses;
    int source , destination;
    int tag = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int masterArray[] = {5,6,8,10,12,3,9,-1,3,7};
    int max , globalMax = -100000;
    int flag = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &myRank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &numOfProcesses);
    printf("Process : %d \n" , myRank);

    int masterSize = sizeof(masterArray)/sizeof(int);
    //printf("%d \n" , masterSize);
    int slaveSize = masterSize/(numOfProcesses-1);
    //printf("%d \n" , slaveSize);
    int slaveArray[slaveSize];

     if (myRank == 0){

        for (i=1; i<numOfProcesses; i++){
            for (j=0; j<slaveSize; j++){
                slaveArray[j] = masterArray[k];
               // printf("%d \n" , masterArray[k]);
                k++;
            }

           MPI_Send(slaveArray, slaveSize, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }


       for (i=1; i<numOfProcesses; i++){
            MPI_Recv(max , 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            if (globalMax < max)
                max = globalMax;
        }
        printf("Global Maximum %d \n" , globalMax);

    }

    else{

        MPI_Recv(slaveArray , slaveSize, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        max = slaveArray[0];

        for (i=0; i<slaveSize; i++){
                if (slaveArray[i] > max)
                    max = slaveArray[i];
        }
        printf("Max in %d %d \n" , myRank, max);

         MPI_Send(max , 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

 MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `masterSize` is not perfectly divisible by `numProcesses-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending and receiving messages in MPI always works through addresses. In the following:

```
MPI_Recv(max , 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

...

```
MPI_Send(max , 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

You use the value. You must add `&` to take the address.

You should also learn to use the appropriate collective operations: [`MPI_Scatter`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Scatter.3.php) and [`MPI_Reduce`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Reduce.3.php).

By the way, this line is also in the wrong order:

```
max = globalMax;
```

Please also learn to listen to your compiler! Any reasonable compiler at resonable settings will warn you of passing an integer as an address.